# Using 3rd party exe in visual studio project and then wrapping it into one for online installer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-c++, windows-installer, libcurl

I am quite new to this. What I wanna do is create an online installer-

Run scripts to install my application for my clients. So the client will download only one installer file. 
What that installer will do is fetch the packages from my server, I was thinking of using CURL. for this I got the curl.exe for windows and I wanna bind it to my program.

When I build my application it generates the program specific exe, and that exe requires curl.exe. I want to wrap both of them in one package and use the curl.exe without notifying the client.

Really need help on this. thanks

Comment: You could use a library that has functionality of CURL but is called from your single .exe: http://sourceforge.net/projects/libcurl-net/

Comment: I am also looking into that, I was hoping that if there is another way to use that curl.exe then we can probably reduce the amount of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either use a library that has the functionality you want so you don't need a separate .exe or you could embed the required 3rd party exe into your application and extract it at run time:

1. Add the exe to your application
2. Change it's build action to **Embedded Resource**
3. Use the following code to extract it at runtime:

---

```
private void ExtractFromAssembly()
{
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    var input = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Namespace.curl.exe");
    //Write the stream out to a new file at a path of your choosing
}
```